# fixed position "go-to-top" on scrolling modal overlay always visible

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, modal-dialog, desktop

https://tinyurl.com/l2jpjks

I have:

1. a modal overlay which scrolls
2. a go-to-top anchor on the overlay

Requirement:

- the anchor remains fixed ~50% from the top

My solution:

- position:fixed

Problem:

- the anchor is displayed on desktops ( FF and Chrome ) when there is no overlay
- the anchor is display on mobile FF when there is no overlay ( Chrome and Safari are OK )

Is there a solution where the anchor will remain fixed, only when the overlay is in effect?

THX